# Django Modelform DateTime Picker

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I would like to get a date AND time picker for my django model form.

model:

```
class ServiceBooker(models.Model):
    regnr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    namn = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    telnr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    service_date = models.DateTimeField()
    booked_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    kommentar = models.TextField()
    service_name = models.ForeignKey(ServiceType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    noteringar = models.TextField(default='')
```

forms.py:

```
class ServiceBookerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
                                       widget=forms.DateTimeInput(
                                           format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
                                           attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceBooker
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('noteringar',)
```

But on the website it doesn't show the datetimepicker. I know how to fix the date picker with:

```
'service_date': widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
```

but I would like to get a date AND time picker.

Can anyone help me? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `datetime-local` as type?

Comment: That worked! Many thanks. Didn't find the documentation under widgets. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Marco helped me to find an answer to this question:

Have you tried datetime-local as type? –
Marco

Answer (score 0):

To add a DateTime picker to your Django form, you can use JavaScript libraries like jQuery UI or other third-party libraries, such as Tempus Dominus for Bootstrap. I'll provide an example using Tempus Dominus since it's a popular choice and works well with Bootstrap.

First, include the necessary libraries in your HTML file. Make sure you have included jQuery, Moment.js, and Bootstrap (if you haven't already):

```html
<head>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Moment.js -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- Tempus Dominus CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tempusdominus-bootstrap-5@6.0.0-alpha.17/build/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-5.min.css" />

  <!-- Tempus Dominus JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tempusdominus-bootstrap-5@6.0.0-alpha.17/build/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-5.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript Bundle -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, update your forms.py file to include a custom ID or class for the DateTimeInput widget:

```
class ServiceBookerForm(forms.ModelForm):
service_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
                                   widget=forms.DateTimeInput(
                                       format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
                                       attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'datetimepicker'}))
class Meta:
    model = ServiceBooker
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ('noteringar',)
```

In your template, where you render the form, make sure that the form field with the datetimepicker ID is present. For example:

```html
<form method="post" class="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Finally, add the JavaScript code to initialize the Tempus Dominus DateTime picker for the input field with the datetimepicker ID:

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now, when you load the form on your website, you should see a DateTime picker for the service_date field that allows you to select both date and time.